# How do I change the cursor in emacs for cygwin?

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin

I've looked multiple times online and can't find how to change the cursor type in emacs for cygwin on Windows. I'm trying to get it to the block cursor instead of the thin line which I can never tell which window I'm in. I've seen stuff about editing the .emacs file or the emacs init file but where do I find this if I use cygwin on windows? Any help would be great.

Comment: I am not under windows but try this: Start Emacs and let it tell you where your init file (e.g. .emacs or init.el) is located. To do this, type in the following keybinding: `C-h v user-init-file`. The key biding starts a prompt (for describing a variable) where you type in `user-init-file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do M-x customize-variable cursor-type and pick something better -- either a thicker bar or a block cursor (my favourite).

The default location for your .emacs file should be ~/.emacs.d/init.el interpreting "~" in the same way that cygwin does.

In general, I'd suggesting using the native windows version of Emacs rather than the cygwin one.

Comment: Ok, so I did M-x then customize-variable and it shows "customize-variable:" What do I do after this? I've tried "cursor-type" but that brings me to a page that shows me the different options I can do. I want the box option but how do I apply it?

Comment: I would use a different version of emacs but I'm only allowed the command line for a class I'm taking so I'd like to do the same on my laptop. And I've gotten pretty use to it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a windows/cygwin box with me at the moment. After customize-variable you *should* be able to type cursor-type which *should* give you a dialog you can interact with. You just click the cursor type you want. But I can't test it!

Comment: So this is what I get after I type the "cursor-type"     http://imgur.com/e4pCvq0

Comment: Click on "Value Menu" select "Filled Box". Click on "State" select "Save for Future Sessions". Should do the trick. Assuming clicking works. If you are really doing this in a terminal you are not using Emacs at it's best or easiest to use.

Answer (score 3):

Editing your init file or customizing that variable will only work in a GUI version of emacs.

In this case, Cygwin (and the shell in which it is running) ultimately determines how the cursor looks.  You should be able to change the cursor type by:

- Right-click on the window title bar > Options > Looks > Cursor

My options are:

```
Line
Block
Underscore
```

With an option for `Blinking`

Comment: I guess *this* answer is what most users who google that problem (same in Vim) are looking for. Thanks for solving the obvious issue here.